# Open a form created codes in access

Tags: ms-access

I have a quick question, is it possible to open a form created codes in access? 
I have created my form but I can not find how to perceive its code in Visual Basic

Thank you for your reply

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know is to export your form from access in an ASCII file, but this is not useful. Access forms are completely embedded in the mdb/accdb file and they need access executable to run. Usually you write events functions of the forms of your access project into the vba editor, but you can access properties and design details only from the design view.